# place image next to text inside multicols

Tags: graphics, multicol

I would like to place an image next to my text inside my `multicols*` environment. My thought had been to use the `minipage` environment, where I simply halve my `columnwidth`. But is this really the best way to implement an image next to a picture inside a `multicols*` environment or is there a better way?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pagesize ,landscape, fontsize=5pt, fleqn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=0.75cm,right=0.75cm, top=0.75cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[svgnames,table,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength{\columnsep}{30pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\[x^2 + y^2 = 1\] %here would the image be

\end {multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: if you mean within the same column then yes two minipages each half the columnwidth, or a two column tabular are probably the way to go (well you only need one minipage, for the equation, tou don't need a minipage for the image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking up on David Carlisle's suggestion, but using a second `minipage` to centre the image while not having it bump against the margin. (Obviously, possible without this, too.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.75cm,right=0.75cm, top=0.75cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}
  \lipsum*[1-2]

  \noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \[x^2 + y^2 = 1\]
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{cath}
  \end{minipage}

  \lipsum[3-10]
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image: mathematical cat?]

Answer (score 1):

Why not `wrapfig` inside `multicol`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,wrapfig,graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
  \lipsum*[1]
    \begin{wrapfigure}[10]{l}[0pt]{3.5cm}
    \rule{3cm}{9\baselineskip}
    % Or: your figure:
    %\includegraphics[width=3cm]{<filename goes here>}
    \end{wrapfigure}
  \lipsum[2-4]
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The trouble is, the so-called text is a display maths environment... and only a single line...